# How to filter ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, filter, listbox

the situation is that I have a list with some HubTile(s) in it, is there any way I can filter the ListBox depending on what is written in a TextBox?

For the text box I have the code...

```
private void textBoxSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thanks, all help appreciated!

Comment: For this kind of functionality better to use CollectionViewSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just store the list of HubTiles in a data structure, and when the user enters a search query, do a LINQ query on that list, and reset the list.

```
private List<HubTiles> myTiles;    
private void textBoxSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
       myList.ItemsSource = myTiles.Where(t => t.Title.Contains(textBoxSearch.Text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I go about obtaining a list of the HubTiles I would need to get their title property to be able to filter them

Comment: In your question you stated that you have a list of HubTiles. Just save that list and query it.

Comment: I get an error message when trying to create the list; this is the code:     List<string> listHubTiles = listBoxNotes.Items     any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because there is never a finite amount of HubTils(s) in the list, I have to create the list differently, however I get an error message in doing so, this is the code: `List<string> listHubTiles = listBoxNotes.Items`

Comment: What error are you getting? What is listBoxNotes.Items? Is it HubTiles? If so, you need a List<HubTile> rather than a List<string>. Also, if listBoxNotes is the list box you're trying to filter, you need to keep your list separate from that, otherwise after you filter it, you'll lose the original list.

Comment: Yeah I managed to fix that with the code `List<HubTile> listHubTiles = listBoxNotes.Items.OfType<HubTile>().ToList();` However now I've implemented the ListBox filtering, the content of the list box is deleted? Even if the search text matches the title exactly? Any ideas what's going wrong this time?

Comment: Ah I've just realised that the ListBox's source is from a separate class, so I'm going to have to try and filter that class then apply it to the ListBox, I know how to do the latter, it's just the filtering of the class which is difficult. I have created a list of the class items however I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: What type is the ListBox source? I imagine a Linq query similar to the one above should do the job? Just replace t.Title.Contains with the type you're searching for.

Comment: Ah no, it turned out to be more complicated than that, but I managed to fix it, so it is now fully working. and I am very thankful for all the help!