# How to filter data in xml in listview?

Tags: xml, vb.net, listview

I want to know, how to filter in xml file. I have 1 button search, 1 text box and listview. The situation, when I type in textbox, eg: M and at the listview will appear all title starting in "M".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329122/how-to-filter-listbox)

Comment: @Aimnox The Post is totally different and OP is asking for something else

Answer (score 1):

That's the code that I use for filtering listbox.

```
Public Sub FiltrarListbox(lb As ListBox, filtre As String)
    Dim l As New List(Of Object)
    For Each item As Object In $CompletCollection
        If (item.toString().ToLower.Contains(filtre.ToLower)) Then
            l.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
    lb.DataSource = l
    lb.ClearSelected()
End Sub
```

You need to save the complet list of objects of the listbox and then filter out of the complet colletion the ones that you want, copy them to a new list and set the new list as datasource of your listbox.